# Force browser to ignore HTML 5 features

Tags: html, firefox

I have a legacy website which renders correctly in FF 3.6, IE 7 to 8 etc but fails in FF 9.

The issue is that an old (pre HTML 5) third party JS framework (Woodstock) used by the site adds a `HIDDEN` attribute to some HTML elements, so when I look at the HTML in firebug I see code like:

```
<table id="foo" hidden="">
```

These pages are being served with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

This worked fine on browsers designed for HTML 4 which did not have a `HIDDEN` attribute.  But the latest browsers that support HTML 5 interpret this attribute and hide elements that I need to be visible.

It will be very difficult to modify the (unsupported) third party framework to avoid the use of the `HIDDEN` attribute.

Is it possible to force browsers to render pages as though they are HTML 4, and not make any interpretation of HTML 5 features?  Other suggestions welcome...

Comment: XHTML is neither HTML 4 nor 5. You're probably also serving the document with the MIME type `text/html`?

Comment: It is being served as text/html (separate issue, right?).  I will first try changing just the DOCTYPE as Zee suggests.

Comment: Yes, the issue with serving XHTML documents as `text/html` is that you're just serving HTML soup. XHTML should be strictly interpreted as XML, which is the supposed benefit of using XHTML in the first place. To do that, you need to serve XHTML documents with the `application/xhtml+xml` MIME type.

Comment: +1 - This is a great question and really shines a light on one area where browsers are falling short - backward compatibility and how the race to support HTML5 breaks that.  What's the point of having all these various `doctype` options if browsers, for the most part, ignore them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Browsers other than IE just implement one HTML (well, with the exception of quirks mode).

However all the `hidden` attribute does is trigger some style rules in the UA stylesheet.  You can add your own style rules to just override those.  How complicated those rules need to be depends on what elements the framework adds the elements to, but one comprehensive approach would be to copy the various `display` rules from the HTML5 spec or from http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/layout/style/html.css with the exception of the ones involving `hidden` and just put them in a stylesheet that your page links to.

Comment: Boris, is it a requirement that the hidden attribute be implemented via display:none as it seems to be? The problem is that the relatively low specificity makes it very easy to inadvertently override the rule. For example, see http://jsfiddle.net/yYemx/1/ If the JS is written first and only run in an unusual situation, and the CSS added later by a different person, then the CSS writer is unlikely to be aware that the very common rule they are adding  will break the use of the hidden attribute.

Comment: For a web browser, it's a requirement, yes.  See http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/rendering.html#hidden-elements which is a normative requirement for web browsers.

Comment: Thanks.  Problem fixed by styling the particular elements with display:table.  Not elegant, but my preferred option in this situation since it is very targeted and is guaranteed not to mess up other elements.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should be declaring the correct DOCTYPE. If it's truly HTML4, you should declare it as HTML4, not XHTML.

See http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html for the different types you can use.

Comment: Thanks.  I will try changing the DOCTYPE and let you know if it works.