# how to shim elem.hidden properly

Tags: javascript, html, polyfills

### Introduction

[`elem.hidden`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/editing.html#the-hidden-attribute) is a new property that allows to hide elements and detect whether they are hidden.

The browser support isn't great so I want to shim it. If I were to shim this property what should it be shimmed to in terms of setting a CSS property through `elem.style`.

### Naive implementation of Shim

```
Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, "hidden", {
  get: function get() {
    return this.style.<???>;
  },
  set: function set(v) {
    this.style.<???> = v ? <???> : <???>
  },
  configurable: true
});
```

### Question

- Should it set `elem.style.display` to `"none"` or `<original value>` ?
- Should it set `elem.style.visibility` to `"hidden"` or `"visible"` ?

Comment: Most browsers that don't support the hidden attribute also don't support Object.defineProperty.

Comment: @kennebec works in >= IE8, and other browsers are usually at their latest version where it works as well.

Comment: @kennebec hence it's the naive implementation. The full shim uses a shimmed `Object.defineProperty` for IE8+ and pals and uses a htc file for IE6/7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsers are required to implement the hidden attribute as `[hidden] { display:none }`

See Boris Zbarsky's answer to [Force browser to ignore HTML 5 features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874841/force-browser-to-ignore-html-5-features/8876078#comment11095801_8876078), and the subsequent comments.

Note that this is done via the user-agent style sheet, so it has a very low specificity, and is easily overridden by a more specific style, even those that don't mention the hidden attribute.

Although I think this is a terrible way to implement the hidden attribute, those are the rules. The nearest you can get to that behaviour is to put `[hidden] { display:none }` as near as you can to the very start of the first stylesheet on your HTML page, rather than applying directly to the style property of the element, where it will have a very high specificity.

In terms of the element property, [the HTML5 spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/editing.html#the-hidden-attribute) says "The hidden IDL attribute must reflect the content attribute of the same name.", so that's the only thing you should be adding via Object.defineProperty. However, kennebec's comment that Object.defineProperty isn't much more widely supported is probably valid.

Comment: Since "it's a terrible way to implement the hidden attribute" what would be a better way?

Comment: @Raynos - That's an interesting question. For browsers, I think it would have been better to create a new css property that had a similar behaviour to display:none or visibility:collapse. Suppose you could say something like [hidden] { -moz-relevance:irrelevant; } etc. then it would be overridable only by another css rule targeting that particular property. The downside would be another addition to the proliferation of CSS properties that already hide content.

Comment: @Raynos - IMHO, It should be implemented the same (or nearly the same) as an `<input type="hidden" />`.  Ie, you can't accidentally override it with css: http://jsfiddle.net/WXy4W/

Comment: Unfortunately, that CSS selector is not precise enough if you've ever overridden the display property. You may have to use `!important`...

Answer (score 1):

`visibility: hidden` elements still need to be rendered as they take space on the screen, so `display: none` is much closer to `.hidden = true` because `display: none`elements can and will be ignored rendering-wise.